# Does a Christian have to believe in Hell?

Tags: hell

I do remember I've read somewhere that modern Christians are no longer required to believe in Hell. Like, it's optional. I've now googled but no such info appeared again. Therefore asking knowlegeable people here - which Church document says the Hell is optional if it is really so.

Comment: You're really going to have to be more specific. Many Christian groups have no structure by which anyone could mandate a particular belief such as the existence of Hell. Do you have in mind a particular group?

Comment: I wonder if you're thinking of "[Love Wins](http://www.amazon.com/Love-Wins-About-Heaven-Person/dp/006204964X)" by Rob Bell. Also, just as a side point, the only person qualified to speak for all Christians (i.e. Jesus Christ) has a terribly annoying habit of not always clearly answering the same way to everyone who asks...

Comment: Jehovah witnesses don't believe in Hell as a place of torture

Comment: Hell is actually a Zoroastrian belief. The Jewish belief was that death is a place of darkness, a pit, etc. A place of no afterlife.  Christianity borrowed the idea and changed it slightly.  That's why hell as you know it is not in the old testament.

Comment: If one believes (1) the book of Revelation and (2) what Jesus said about Hell, it's kind of hard to deny the existence of Hell.

Comment: According to the docrine grid at CARM belief in Eternal torment is not essential for regeneration and saving faith in Christ. http://carm.org/doctrine-grid See items 22 & 24. "Affirming the doctrines in this grey section are signs of significant lack of understanding of biblical theology. Nevertheless, believing them does not negate salvation."

Comment: @unregistered-matthew7.7: There's very little Jesus said directly about hell. Most of it was either clearly or possibly allegorical. There's far more he says about heaven, which can be taken literally. And the book of Revelation has many interpretations, and most of them are also allegorical.

Comment: There are several groups that do not believe in Hell. But your question seems to be about a group that says believing in Hell is optional; it is not a topic belief that can keep you from entering the Kingdom. There are some liberal groups that are pretty much optional on everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the words of Christ as authoritative for describing Christianity, I'd say "**Ya.**" (See Matt. 5:22, 29, 30, 10:28, 18:9, 23:15, 33, etc.)

But of course, you can *call* yourself a Christian and believe whatever you want.  There don't seem to be any "Christianity police" regulating what people associate with the faith.

---

*Of course, it is also possible to be a Christian and be ignorant of the doctrine of hell, which doesn't necessarily preclude you from being a Christian. (That actually seems to be the norm.)*

Answer (score 2):

As one of the comments mentioned your probably thinking of "[Love Wins](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/006204964X)". In the book, he does not deny the existence of hell as a real place , rather what he is questioning the *nature* of hell.

So in the same way, to answer your question, I do not believe there is a major branch of Christianity where the existence of Hell is optional, only the *nature* of what hell is, is being debated (i.e. who goes there, nature of the punishment, does it last forever or just a time, are the damned forgiven at some point or are they [completely destroyed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilationism), etc).

Also check out "[Sense and Nonsense about Heaven and Hell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0310254280)" by Ken Boa on this topic, its a short and great read on the subject.

Comment: I almost became Ken Boa's research assistant a few years back :)

Answer (score 1):

Any student of the Bible should undertake very seriously to understand the passages in Jas' answer.  Do those passages represent the truth? ***Yes.***  Is passing a test on those passages a condition of salvation? ***No.***

There's a big difference between what is the necessary condition for salvation, and the body of doctrine a teacher should teach. There are several places in the Bible which offer very simplistic formulas for salvation. For example:

Romans 10:9

> if you confess with your mouth Jesus as Lord, and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be saved

If we take this passage to be literally true, it is hope to the person who just grasped some doctrine, but probably cannot recite and defend doctrine at the level of, say, the Athanasian Creed.  This passage also does **not** say, "Teachers, be satisfied that you're done when these two conditions are met."

As I said above, there is a big difference between teaching something false and not understanding all of doctrine.

**1) Biblical evidence:**

James 3:1

> Not many of you should become teachers, my fellow believers, because you know that we who teach will be judged more strictly.

**2) Church history evidence:**

[Martin Luther's 95 Theses](http://www.spurgeon.org/~phil/history/95theses.htm) expresses all kinds of anathemas to the hierarchy of the Roman Catholic Church at the time. But very few make any negative reference to the rank-and-file Catholic pew sitters at the time. The worst accusation is that they might trust in the Pope's prescribed works and "lose the fear of God through them."